# Is there a hotkey to switch between tabs in Caja?

Tags: 16.04, mate, filemanager, caja

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 MATE, and am wondering whether there is a hotkey to switch between tabs in Caja? In Nautilus, it is possible to switch tabs with STRG + Tab, but in Caja, this doesn't work. Is there another hotkey, or is it possible to define STRG + Tab as hotkey for this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ctrl + page_down / page_up`.

Works for me in `Caja 1.12.7, ubuntu mate 16.04.2`

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks. But it is sort of impractical, because I can't do it with 1 hand only on my keyboard. Is there a way to change the hotkey?

Comment: "The shortcut is inherited from GTK. Any application that uses GtkNotebook for tabs has these shortcuts". [Source](https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues/73).  I'll do a little searching on how to set it to `ctrl + tab`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It seems somewhat strange since ctrl + tab seems to work in pretty much any other application with tabs. The ctrl + page up/down solution seems impractical because it stops at the last tab and doesn't switch to the first